# How print col1, col2 and their difference in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print col1, col2, col1 - col2 from a df.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df['c1'], df['c2'],df['c1']-df['c2'])
```

gives

```
0    10
1    11
2    12
Name: c1, dtype: int64 0    100
1    110
2    120
Name: c2, dtype: int64 0    -90
1    -99
2   -108
dtype: int64
```

I want

```
col1 col2 diff    
10 100 -90
11 110 -99
12 120 -108
```

Seems easy, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: first `df["diff"] = df['c1']-df['c2']`, next `print(df)` or `print( df[ ["c1", "c2", "diff"] ] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['diff'] = df['c1'] - df['c2']
df.head()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score 2):

First create column with new values

```
 df["diff"] = df['c1']-df['c2']
```

and later print it

```
 print(df)
```

or (if you have more columns and you want to skip them)

```
print( df[ ["c1", "c2", "diff"] ] )
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':100}, {'c1':11,'c2':110}, {'c1':12,'c2':120}]

df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df["diff"] = df['c1']-df['c2']

print(df)

print( df[ ["c1", "c2", "diff"] ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) this give you more flexibility

```
new_df = df.assign(diff = df['c1'].sub(df['c2']))
print(new_df)
   c1   c2   diff
0  10  100    -90
1  11  110    -99
2  12  120   -108
```